# How to export result SQL from DB2 IBM

Tags: t-sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Do have any idea on how to export big data file from DB2 Power 8? Size approximately about 500 million data row.
Came across option to export by text, print and file. print is not an option for me. the text option return me  split text files (field). as for file option, i don't have access to set up new library to save the files in DB2.

Used the navigator as well, due to the size, its not responding..

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Use any Database Manager, I use DBEAVER as suggested below, but there are many tools right for you (Squirrel, HeidiSQL...)

Comment: Where do you want to export to? Excel won't handle that many rows in a single spreadsheet. are you trying to get it into another database?

Comment: If you want it comma separated you could try using CPYTOIMPF to write it to a file on the IFS (assuming you have enough spare disk space, obviously), and then FTP to download it. I'd  create a clone to practise on, with just a few rows, using the CPYF TORCD parameter. Better to do the majority of the processing server-side for such a big table.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to use DBeaver to connect to DB2.

[image: Create new connection to DB2 from DBeaver]

Comment: I honestly think this is the wrong approach with such a vast amount of data.

Answer (score -1):

Try the EXPORT command from a command line

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html

Comment: Appears to relate to DB2 LUW not DB2 for i.